# Email subject displays nil when using UserDefault

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have 5 view controllers, and you input your name on screen 2, and it is supposed to pass its data so that in screen 5, the email screen, the subject has your name. Should be like: screen 2: "Bill", screen 5: "Name: 'Bill'", but instead it displays "Name: nil". Im using UserDefault to pass data,
Here is my screen 2 code:

```
   @IBAction func extButton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "whotoclass", sender: self)

}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    UserDefaults.standard.setValue("your username", forKey: "UserName")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(nil, forKey: "UserName")

}
```

And screen 5:

```
let strUserName = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "UserName")


var myString = String()

@IBOutlet var pickerview2: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

let reason = ["Busy - General","Filming","Editing","Computer Task","Helping","Getting Set Up"]

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return reason[row]
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return reason.count
}

@IBAction func sendButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let toRecipients = ["thejoshytv@gmail.com"]

    let mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()

    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self

    mc.setToRecipients(toRecipients)
    mc.setSubject("Media Team Task")

    mc.setMessageBody("Hi There, A Notice to tell you that \(strUserName) will not be in class today.", isHTML: false)

    present(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {

    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "reasontosent", sender: self)


}
```

Comment: `UserDefaults.standard.setValue(nil, forKey: "UserName")` Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by deleting the completely unnecessary

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(nil, forKey: "UserName")
```

You're basically setting the value to nil.

On the other hand, UserDefauls saves periodically to disk, so by setting that to nil at some point it will be persisted on the disk (the previous value will be erased).

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize

> Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals,
>   use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic
>   synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or
>   if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though
>   you have not made any changes.